# what will be the code to move to previous textfield?

Tags: javascript

i have the code if i press down button it goes to next textfield but to go to previous textfield what should be the code ...

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
function handleKeyDownEvent(elementRef,eventRef)
{ 
 var charCode = (window.event) ? eventRef.keyCode : eventRef.which;

 //alert(charCode);

 // Arrow keys (37:left, 38:up, 39:right, 40:down)...




if (charCode == 40)
 {
  if (window.event)
   window.event.keyCode = 9;
  else
   event.which = 9;

  return true;
 } 



 return true;
}



</script>
</head>
<body>
<table width="433" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
                <td width="235" align="center"><input type="text" onKeyDown="handleKeyDownEvent(this,event);" onKeyUp="handleKeyUpEvent(this,event);"></td>
                <td width="235"  align="center"><input type="text" onKeyDown="handleKeyDownEvent(this,event);" onKeyUp="handleKeyUpEvent(this,event);"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td width="235"  align="center"><input type="text" onKeyDown="handleKeyDownEvent(this,event);" onKeyUp="handleKeyUpEvent(this,event);"></td>
                <td width="235"  align="center"><input type="text" onKeyDown="handleKeyDownEvent(this,event);" onKeyUp="handleKeyUpEvent(this,event);"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <input type="radio" id="check" name="check" checked>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="radio" id="check" name="check" checked>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="check" name="check"></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="check" name="check"></td>
      </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the keyCode 9 is simulating pressing the 'tab' key. Essentially what you want to do to go backwards is simulate 'shift' + 'tab'. Shift's code is 16, so have a go at adding a `window.event.keyCode = 16;` line above the similar line with 9, and an `event.which = 16;` above the other.

If this doesn't work, you may need to chain them together in some way so that the key-up event associated with the shift-key event triggers a simulated press of tab. This could be done by adding another event handler before or after the one you already have. The handler should be similar to the one you already have, but change it to a keyUp handler and check for key 16 instead of 40.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to read a [discussion about that here](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-23648.html)... they fixed a similar problem.